# Accessing Associative Array: Why does this (probably incorrect) code work?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

***QUESTION:***

In the second (following) code snippet, in the *inner* `foreach` loop (that is the `foreach` loop nested in another `foreach` loop), the `$value` corresponds to an element of the `$studentCoursesStudied`, and NOT the `$studentCoursesStudied` array itself, right?

The [correct way](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to access the value of an element of the `$studentCoursesStudied` array would be:

```
$studentCoursesStudied[$key]
```

But they are accessing the value of each element of the `$studentCoursesStudied` array like

```
$value['an-element-name/key']
```

**where $value corresponds to an element of the array, Not the array itself! Why?**

***BACKGROUND:***
I am reading a PHP script written by somebody else for learning, and I don't understand how they are accessing the values in an associative array at a point. So I wrote this example code to ask this question.

Here is a `Student` class and a student has a property containing an associative array, by the name of `recordCoursesStudied`.

```
class Student {
    public $studentName;
    public $studentAge;
    public $studentCoursesStudied = null;

    function __construct($studentName, $studentGpa) {
        $this->studentName = $studentName;
        $this->studentGpa = $studentGpa;
    }

    function recordCoursesStudied ($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType) {
        $this->studentCoursesStudied[] = array(
            'courseName' => $courseName;
            'courseNumber' => $courseNumber;
            'creditHours' => $creditHours;
            'maxMarks' => $maxMarks;
            'courseType' => $courseType;
        );  
    }
}
```

Then we want to access the elements of `recordCoursesStudied` from another class `Whatever` from its method `newCourseRecord`.

***Note:*** In the block comment after the inner `foreach` loop, I have written the same snippet with better names to make things clear.

```
class Whatever {
    private $students;
    private $currentStudent;

    function __construct () {
        $this->newStudent('Zarah', 3.4);
        $this->newCourseRecord('DBMS', 'BR223', 3, 100, 'Core');
        $this->doTheWork();
    }

    function newStudent($studentName, $studentGpa) {
        $this->students[$studentName] = new Student($studentName, $studentGpa);
        $this->currentStudent = $studentName;
    }

    function newCourseRecord($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType) {
        $this->students[$this->studentName]->recordCoursesStudied($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType);
    }

    function doTheWork() {
        ...
        foreach ($this->students as $key=>$value) {
            ...
            foreach($value->studentCoursesStudied as $key=>$value) { /****************************/
                ...
                //Echo each property of $studentCoursesStudied.
                someOtherFunction($value['courseName'], $value['courseNumber'], $value['creditHours'], $value['maxMarks'], $value['courseType']);
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        /*foreach ($this->students as $studentKey=>$studentValue) {
            ...
            foreach($studentValue->studentCoursesStudied as $courseKey=>$courseValue) { /****************************/
                ...
                //Echo each property of $studentCoursesStudied.
                /*someOtherFunction($courseValue['courseName'], $courseValue['courseNumber'], $courseValue['creditHours'], $courseValue['maxMarks'], $courseValue['courseType']);
                ...
            }
            ...
        }*/
        ...
    }

}
```

In the given code, in the `foreach` loop highlighted by `*`s, they have accessed the values in the `Student::studentCoursesStudied` array by doing something like:

```
$value-of-an-element-in-array['key-of-an-element-in-array']
```

But shouldn't elements of associative array accessed like `name-of-array['key-of-an-element-in-array']` ?

Comment: I'm a little confused here as you [shouldn't be able to access that private property](https://eval.in/318112) directly

Comment: @scrowler Hey I just wrote this in a hurry to demonstrate the problem. I'll change the access modifiers (but this may have some other small mistakes as well)

Comment: You have an error in your second class. You have not set `$this->studentName` in method `newCourseRecord` at all. You better post the original code

Comment: @winston86 That is Hugeee! Let me correct this and compile it

Comment: Then edit and add in `__construct()`  `$this->newStudent($this->studentName = 'Zarah', 3.4);`

Comment: And you don't returns any values in your methods or set them. It will never work, sorry.

Comment: Best you sort out the inconsistencies so the real issue can he highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure method recordCoursesStudied wasn't like this?

```
$this->studentCoursesStudied[] = array(
        'courseName' => $courseName;
        'courseNumber' => $courseNumber;
        'creditHours' => $creditHours;
        'maxMarks' => $maxMarks;
        'courseType' => $courseType;
    );
```

It would make sense if studentCoursesStudied was an array with information about multiple courses (and each array item is an array of fields that describe a single course). Then your nested foreach would make sense, except you can't use $key and $value as loop variables for both loops.

Comment: Yes, I missed the `[]`. It's a typo- does it make a big difference?

Comment: It creates another level in this multidimentional array. A statement like `$a[] = $b` puts $b as the last item into an array $a like this: `array($b)`. And then if you do `$a[] = $c` $a's gonna become `array($b, $c)`. In your case $this->studentCoursesStudied is gonna become something like: `array(array('courseName' => 'course1', ...), array('courseName' => 'course2', ...), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You construct the first class and set the values in

```
$this->students[$studentName] = new Student($studentName, $studentGpa);
```

Than

```
 function newCourseRecord(
                 $courseName, 
                 $courseNumber, 
                 $creditHours, 
                 $maxMarks, 
                 $courseType) {
                    $this->students[$this->studentName]->recordCoursesStudied(
                           $courseName, 
                           $courseNumber, 
                           $creditHours, 
                           $maxMarks, 
                           $courseType);
 }
```

Than you access the values in loop

```
    foreach ($this->students as $key=>$value) {
        ...
        foreach($value->studentCoursesStudied as $key=>$value) { /****************************/
            ...
            //Echo each property of $studentCoursesStudied.
            someOtherFunction($value['courseName'], $value['courseNumber'], $value['creditHours'], $value['maxMarks'], $value['courseType']);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

That is correct.

Comment: Here, `$value` corresponds to each `element`'s value in the `$studentCoursesStudied` array, and NOT `$studentCoursesStudied` itself, right? Shouldn't they access the elements in the array like `$studentCoursesStudied[$key]`? My question is about the syntax used to access the elements of the array

Comment: Hello @Zarah. Your code and your question is quite confusing because foreach variables for each loop have the same names. This code is not gonna work. But see my answer, maybe I guessed correctly what you were trying to say)

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
class Student {
private $studentName;
private $studentAge;
private $studentCoursesStudied = null; //private  not run out this class so you can define a public function to get it

public function getStudentCoursesStudied() {
  return $this -> $studentCoursesStudied;
}

function __construct($studentName, $studentGpa) {
    $this->studentName = $studentName;
    $this->studentGpa = $studentGpa;
}

function recordCoursesStudied ($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType) {
    $this->studentCoursesStudied = array(
        'courseName' => $courseName;
        'courseNumber' => $courseNumber;
        'creditHours' => $creditHours;
        'maxMarks' => $maxMarks;
        'courseType' => $courseType;
    );  
}
} 


class Whatever {
private $students = array(); // define is a empty array();
private $currentStudent;

function __construct () {
    $this->newStudent('Zarah', 3.4);
    $this->newCourseRecord('DBMS', 'BR223', 3, 100, 'Core');
    $this->doTheWork();
}

function newStudent($studentName, $studentGpa) {
    $this->students[$studentName] = new Student($studentName, $studentGpa);
    $this->currentStudent = $studentName;
}

function newCourseRecord($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType) {
//you use $this -> studentName but i n't find where's defined i think you want to use $this -> currentStudent
    $this->students[$this-> currentStudent]->recordCoursesStudied($courseName, $courseNumber, $creditHours, $maxMarks, $courseType); 
}

function doTheWork() {
    ...
    foreach ($this->students as $key=>$value) {
        ...
        foreach($value-> getStudentCoursesStudied() as $key=>$value) { /****************************/
            ...
            //Echo each property of $studentCoursesStudied.
            someOtherFunction($value['courseName'], $value['courseNumber'], $value['creditHours'], $value['maxMarks'], $value['courseType']);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    /*foreach ($this->students as $studentKey=>$studentValue) {
        ...
        foreach($studentValue->studentCoursesStudied as $courseKey=>$courseValue) { /****************************/
            ...
            //Echo each property of $studentCoursesStudied.
            /*someOtherFunction($courseValue['courseName'], $courseValue['courseNumber'], $courseValue['creditHours'], $courseValue['maxMarks'], $courseValue['courseType']);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }*/
    ...
}
```

}